# $T$-nilpotent ideals

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, ideals

Recall that a subset $I$ of a ring $R$ is left (resp.,
right) $T$-nilpotent in case for every sequence $$a_1,a_2,\cdots $$
in $I$ there is an $n$ such that $a_1\cdots a_n=0$ (resp.,
$a_n\cdots a_1=0$). Every nilpotent ideal is left and right
$T$-nilpotent.

Is there any characterization for rings $R$ in which the Jacobson radical is $T$-nilpotent?

Comment: I suppose you are well aware of this, but just in case other readers might be, like me, a little forgetful, a ring is left-perfect iff $J(R)$ is left T-nilpotent *and* $R/J(R)$ is semisimple, i.e., left-Artinian (where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical).

Comment: Yes, I've seen that before but I don't know exactly where:) Could you please give a reference for this fact.? And since for most of the rings (i.e. left/right Artinian) one has that R/J(R) is semisimple it seems that the answer would be that J(R) is $T$-nilpotent if and only $R$ is left perfect.

Comment: See Lam, *A First Course in Noncommutative Rings* (2d edition Springer 2001, GTM 131), §23 ("Perfect and Semiperfect Rings"), esp. around definition 23.18 (of left-perfect rings) and theorem 23.20 (Bass criterion).